# Use Django Allauth with inertia.js & Vue

Tags: django, django-allauth, inertiajs

I'm trying to using Django Allauth with inertia + vue combination.

Take a view like e.g.:

```
from inertia import render

def about(request):
    return render(request, "About", props={"pageName": "About"})
```

I have my project configured in a way that it will render this inside `About.vue` like so:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps<{
  pageName: string;
}>();
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <h1>This is the {{ pageName }} page</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

How would I go about connecting this to Django Allauth?

Thinking of something like extending from e.g. their LoginView:

```
from inertia import render
from allauth.account.views import LoginView

def login(request):
    return render(request, "Login", props={"context_obj": ?})
```

Not sure what I can do to pass the context object through. Anyone any ideas?